# 3/4 Password requirements

Tags: php, database, passwords

I'm trying to have my website require the user (when they create an account) to contain 3/4 password requirements. The requirements I would like the password to contain are: 1. Numbers 2. Lower case letters 3. Upper case letters 4. Special case symbols/characters. Here is the code I have so far:

```
    $passwordspecs='^(?=.{8, 20})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$ | ^(?=.{8, 20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@$#£&]).*$ | ^(?=.{8, 20})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@$#£&]).*$ | ^(?=.{8, 20})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@$#^£&]).*$';
    if(preg_match('/$passwordspecs/', $_POST['password'])) {
        $results="INSERT INTO Operator (Username, Password, PermissionLevel)
        VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[plevel]')";
        echo "One user added!";
    }
    else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Password needs to contain 3/4 requirements!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
```

I was finally able to get rid of the error messages that were coming up but now no matter if I enter 3/4 or 4/4 password requirements it goes straight to the else statement and I get the alert message. Any ideas on what's wrong or maybe there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: (Off topic) Please don't do this.  You'll only piss off your users.

Comment: Use single regexes for the single requirements. Put them in an array, iterate over them and count.

Comment: `'/$passwordspecs/'` => you need double quotes `"/$passwordspecs/"`, or the variable will not get parsed and replaced

Comment: on an important sidenote: do not store passwords as plain text!

Comment: be careful your code is vulnerable to sql injections

Comment: Seriously you are that worried about a "strong" password and then store it in plain text?

Comment: Thank you for all the security comments but that is something I will not have to worry about for now

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is here:

```
preg_match('/$passwordspecs/', $_POST['password'])
```

You are trying to access value of variable **$passwordspecs** in a single quotes. You need to use double quotes instead. Otherwise it is treated as a string. Change it to:

```
preg_match("/{$passwordspecs}/", $_POST['password'])
```

But you have more problems than that:

1. Do not store password as a string, use some sort of hashing algorithm as **Garytje** suggested.
2. Do not directly insert data into database that user provided. (DO NOT TRUST USER INPUT), in other words use prepared statements or else someone will inject SQL code.

And in my opinion, as a customer/user, I hate when I have to choose a password like that, its hard to remember later on. I am registering on your website (means you get +1 user) why cant I choose password whatever the "hack" I want it to be? Why do I have to follow your rules. Maybe I want my password to be an empty space?

And also by telling users that they have to input a password in that kind of format, it gives out sensitive information to possible "hackers" because then they can narrow down all possible passwords to match your format and attack using **brute force**.

Comment: Thank you for the security info but luckily I won't have to worry about that for now. I tried changing it to double quotes but I'm still having the same results/issue

Comment: I agree with your password recommendation, but I am only creating what I am being told to do =/

Comment: Try this: `"/{$passwordspecs}/"`